# using .includes with .map to find matching values

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to test if one array contains an id which exists in another array. Here's the first Array:

```
var ids = [
    "N06Jrz5hx6Q9bcVDBBUrF3GKSTp2",
    "eLLfNlWLkTcImTRqrYnU0nWuu9P2"
]
```

And here's an example of how the user object looks like:

```
var userExample = {
    "category": "Chemia",
    "coins": 100,
    "friends": {},
    "level": "Liceum",
    "newAnswers": false,
    "nickname": "czainusek",
    "notifications": true,
    "safety": true,
    "tagID": "drawable/icon_other1",
    "tasksUploaded": 0,
    "works": {
        "-LI1z-yO4MJnPwrdwHGl": "-LI1z-tB6EpqIhJwzchP",
        "-LIHAwCpc84UQqGeT1bU": "-LIHAw8RuTZxfgz0ef8G",
        "-LIHB2Ov5B-4XqpM79Av": "-LIHB2IPmMqOxa3UPFxs"
    },
    "id": "Nqez1dKRJ6aEpOb4BuUOK75iJoJ2"
}
```

And I have an array of said objects. They all look like this:

```
var usersExamples = [
    {
        "category": "Chemia",
        "coins": 100,
        "friends": {},
        "level": "Liceum",
        "newAnswers": false,
        "nickname": "czainusek",
        "notifications": true,
        "safety": true,
        "tagID": "drawable/icon_other1",
        "tasksUploaded": 0,
        "works": {
            "-LI1z-yO4MJnPwrdwHGl": "-LI1z-tB6EpqIhJwzchP",
            "-LIHAwCpc84UQqGeT1bU": "-LIHAw8RuTZxfgz0ef8G",
            "-LIHB2Ov5B-4XqpM79Av": "-LIHB2IPmMqOxa3UPFxs"
        },
        "id": "Nqez1dKRJ6aEpOb4BuUOK75iJoJ2"
    },
    {
        "coins": 20,
        "friends": {},
        "level": "Gimnazjum",
        "newAnswers": false,
        "nickname": "Tomasz ",
        "notifications": true,
        "safety": true,
        "tagID": "drawable/emot_icons1",
        "tasksUploaded": 5,
        "id": "SAlVGjXIagdDuJrHYO4i6LwzUql2"
    }
]
```

So knowing this I tried something like this:

```
console.log(reportIds.includes(users.map(user => user.id)));
```

This returned false. But if I try an id like this:

```
console.log(reportIds.includes('N06Jrz5hx6Q9bcVDBBUrF3GKSTp2'));
```

it returns true.

The object with said Id exists. I checked the ids manually. I tried this:

```
console.log(reportIds.includes(['8VbBNBDrT1Z3kmyaQzy6LqskcOT2', 'N06Jrz5hx6Q9bcVDBBUrF3GKSTp2'].map(id => id)));
```

But this returned false.

Same with this:

```
console.log(reportIds.includes(['8VbBNBDrT1Z3kmyaQzy6LqskcOT2', 'N06Jrz5hx6Q9bcVDBBUrF3GKSTp2']));
```

So how can I check which ids are in the `ids` array?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a combination of [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`Array#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) for that :

```js
let ids = [
    "N06Jrz5hx6Q9bcVDBBUrF3GKSTp2",
    "eLLfNlWLkTcImTRqrYnU0nWuu9P2"
];

let usersExamples = [
    {
        "id": "Nqez1dKRJ6aEpOb4BuUOK75iJoJ2"
    },
    {
        "id": "SAlVGjXIagdDuJrHYO4i6LwzUql2"
    },
    {
        "id": "eLLfNlWLkTcImTRqrYnU0nWuu9P2"
    }
];

let result = usersExamples.filter(u => ids.includes(u.id));
console.log(result);
```

Comment: This is precisely what I needed. Any idea why it failed to return true with `map`? I'll select as best in 7 min

Comment: You were basically doing `ids.includes(anotherArray)` which won't work in your case. You need to test each value independently, not the whole array.

Comment: Wouldn't `ids.includes(anotherArray.map(val => val.id))` do precisely that though?

Comment: No, `anotherArray.map(...)` still gives another Array, not single values.

Comment: Ok then. Thanks! I'll select in 4 mins